# Magento 2 nginx 404 error permission denied on setup

Tags: nginx, permissions, not-found, magento-setup

I have problem with setting up project the nginx is working fine and it is setup correctly, but it gives me 404 Not Found page when I try to access the url.
[image: The directory permissions]

The log:
`2022/12/06 19:01:26 [crit] 285154#285154: *3 stat() "/home/kristijan/Documents/VAPO/vapo/pub/errors/404.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: vapo.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "vapo.local"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command that tells you what exactly Problem is in the Nginx

```
nginx -t
```

Will show you the Correct  Nginx Errors.

Then restart your Nginx and hopefully, all goes well.

If you need more help please let me know.